# What is the meaning of the sentence "you have to be possessed which you can't will"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, contemporary-english

There is this video on John Baldessari and he says there's three things a young artist should know. I couldn't get the second one because I could not figure out the sentence. Take a look at it:

> You have to be possessed which you can't will

If one wants to see the tip in context, it appears at 4:58 in this 5:54 video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eU7V4GyEuXA

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that sentence, the verb *[will](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/will#Verb_2)* is used with the sense “To choose to (do something), used to express intention but without any temporal connotations (+ bare infinitive)”.   That is, while one might *wish* to be [possessed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/possessed#Adjective) (that is to say, under the influence of powerful emotions), typically one cannot be possessed just by deciding to be so.